# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null when i move to other page in the website

Tags: javascript, html

I start working an a mockup website with multiple pages, and because i'm pretty new to javascript i encounter the following problem. I start putting some event listeners on different elements on my code, but from some reasons i get a "cannot read property of null" type error when i navigate to different pages.

So far I have tried to:

- Move the script tag in html everywhere on the page on the top, above the close body tag, below the body tag, below the HTML tag, in the head tag.
- Call a window.load function
- Put all the EventListeners on a single function and loaded at the beging.

NOTHING WORKS!!!

I want to specify that some of the elements i want to put events on, are display none in css.
Below you can take a look of one of the page that i first encounter the problem.

I hope i expressed myself correctly :)

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rock Festival</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Your Name">
    <meta name="description" content="Example description">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
</head>

<div id="site-wrapper">
<body>
    
    <section id="main-nav" class="d-between">
       <div class="nav-logo">ROCKA</div>
       <div class="nav-item d-between">
          <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">home</a>
          <a href="lineup.html" class="nav-link">lineup</a>
          <a href="location.html" class="nav-link active">location</a>
          <a href="tickets.html" class="nav-link">tickets</a>
          <a href="" class="nav-link">activities</a>
          <a href="" class="nav-link">contest</a>
          <a href="" class="nav-link">food court</a>
       </div>
    </section>
    
<!--    LOCATION SECTION-->
   
     <section id="location" class="d-column">
         <div class="location-img d-flex">KIMBERLY PARK</div>
         <div class="container d-column">
             <div class="kimberly-details d-column">
                 <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Icons/montains-01.png" alt="" class="img-intro">
                 <p class="about-kimberly">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque aliquam saepe beatae doloremque quae odio ullam tempora accusantium. Quia voluptates mollitia, est quidem qui quibusdam nulla ad architecto. Pariatur corporis explicabo reprehenderit nulla vitae neque, nemo necessitatibus, eligendi ex asperiores ut accusamus laboriosam eum quos numquam animi eos ab, deserunt rerum illum. Cupiditate aut ea, enim tempore unde facere eveniet eum ipsum quaerat. Temporibus similique nulla fuga odio officiis hic eveniet perspiciatis explicabo inventore, iusto necessitatibus sit tenetur nostrum qui eum corrupti, recusandae dignissimos illum amet. Illum sit dicta dolore magni nostrum incidunt similique accusamus, quasi. Cum ratione corporis cupiditate.</p>
             </div>
             
             
             <div class="kimberly-photos d-column">
               
                <div class="lightbox-overlay off d-column">
                     <div id="light-img" class="lightbox-content d-column">
                        <img src="" alt="" class="lightbox-img">
                         <div class="lightbox-close">X</div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 
                 <div class="collage-content d-flex">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_1.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_2.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_3.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_4.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_5.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_6.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_7.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_8.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_9.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_10.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_11.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                <img src="..//Graphics/Location/Gallery/pic_12.jpg" alt="" class="img-collage">
                
                
                 </div>
             </div>
             
         </div>
     </section>

     <section id="general-footer" class="d-flex">
         <div class="container d-between">
             <div class="footer-left-content">
                 <div class="footer-logo">ROCKA</div>
                 <div class="footer-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, nemo corporis provident sapiente magnam illo natus porro quis officia.</div>
             </div>
             <div class="footer-center-content d-flex">
                 <div class="footer-column">
                     <p>location</p>
                     <p>lineup</p>
                     <p>tickets</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="footer-column">
                     <p>activities</p>
                     <p>contest</p>
                     <p>food court</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="footer-column">
                     <p>contact</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="footer-right-content d-flex">
                 <div class="footer-text-2">Follow us on</div>
                 <div class="footer-social">
                     <img src="..//Graphics/social/facebook-01.png" alt="">
                     <img src="..//Graphics/social/instagram-01.png" alt="">
                     <img src="..//Graphics/social/youtube-01.png" alt="">
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </section>
          
      </body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </div>
</html>
```

JS

```
const imgCollage = document.querySelectorAll('.img-collage');
const lightBoxClose = document.querySelector('.lightbox-close');
const lightBoxOverlay = document.querySelector('.lightbox-overlay');
const imgContent = document.querySelector('.lightbox-img');


loadEventListeners();


function loadEventListeners() {
    
    lightBoxClose.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
    imgCollage.forEach(img=>img.addEventListener('click', openOnClick));
    
 };


function openOnClick() {
    lightBoxOverlay.classList.toggle('off');
    imgContent.src = this.src;
};

function closeModal(){[enter image description here][1]
    lightBoxOverlay.classList.toggle('off');
};
```

Comment: Why did you put two slashes on the beginning of your image paths?

Comment: Most likely by mistake :). I change it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of **display none** you will get **undefined** in querySelectors, so you can't add listener to it. Display none will cut your element from the DOM.
There are some way to solve it:

1. Check if the variable exist and add listener, but you should removeEventListener when you're going your element to set display none.
2. use **visibility:hidden** - this will only hide your element but still render in DOM

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I first tried the second option but is not working. I even set all the elements to display block. Even so, when i move to another page, i'm getting the same "null error". Then i erase all my JS code, create a new element in HTML and then selected with querySelector or getElementById. Same error. It only shows something when i selected with getElementsByClassName, but i don't wanna receive a HTML collection when all i need it is one element.

Comment: Have you tried fist option? Like if (lightBoxClose) { lightBoxClose.addEventListener } inside loadEventListeners function

Comment: I didn't try because I was a little surprised that I can no longer select an element regardless of it's display option. I will try that one too.

Comment: you sure that elements you need still exist on a page when you navigate throught different pages? Is it landing and everything in one file or you have different html file as it seems by your routing?

Comment: i have multiple html pages

Comment: It was option 1. It WORKED!!!. Thank you very much. So, just to understand how it works. When I have an element that is hidden, I will put an if statement so that the event can be fired only when there is an interaction with that specific element. Maybe is a stupid question, but i try to understand the logic behind it.